# Why does setting a breakpoint make my code work?

Tags: c, xcode, debugging, malloc

I'm very new to `C` so I'm sure I am doing loads wrong however this is puzzling me.

My code should get a title from the user and create a folder in the route directory with that name. It only works if I set a breakpoint on the `makeFolder()` implementation. For some reason that small rest before I click `continue` makes it work (I'm using Xcode).

By *doesn't work* I mean it returns 0 correctly but no folder is created.

This is one of my first attempts at doing anything with `C` and I'm just messing around trying to learn it.

**Edit** Many thanks for your answers and comments. It is now working as expected and I learned a little along the way. You are all scholars and gentlemen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_TITLE_SIZE 256

void setTitle(char* title) {
    char *name = malloc (MAX_TITLE_SIZE);
    printf("What is the title? ");
    fgets(name, MAX_TITLE_SIZE, stdin);

    // Remove trailing newline, if there
    if(name[strlen(name) - 1] == '\n')
        name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';

    strcpy(title, name);
    free(name);
}

// If I set a breakpoint here it works
void makeFolder(char * parent, char * name) {
    char *path = malloc (MAX_TITLE_SIZE);

    if(parent[0] != '/')
        strcat(path, "/");

    strcat(path, parent);
    strcat(path, "/");
    //strcat(path, name);
    //strcat(path, "/");
    printf("The path is %s\n", path);
    mkdir(path, 0777);
    free(path);
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char title[MAX_TITLE_SIZE];
    setTitle(title);
    printf("The title is \'%s\'", title);
    makeFolder(title, "Drafts");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when it doesn't "work"?

Comment: One possible problem here is that in `makeFolder`, you use `strcat` to append to "path", but you've never written anything to path to ensure that it is a nul-terminated string as opposed to garbage data. No idea why a breakpoint would make any difference, but try `*path = 0;` after the `malloc`, to set the first char of the data to a nul terminator. The first parameter to `strcat` has to be a nul-terminated string, or else `strcat` can't find the end of it in order to append.

Comment: You have a lot of unnecessary `malloc` calls. A simple `char path[MAX_TITLE_SIZE]` will work fine.

Comment: @aschepler I've edited it for more clarity

Comment: In response to your edit - of course it's also possible that the garbage data does contain a 0 byte, so `strcat` is appending, but then you're trying to create a directory with an impossible name, because the garbage data contains disallowed characters.

Comment: @casablanca I tried `char path[MAX_TITLE_SIZE]` but `path` ends up pointing to `$㏔\343\217\330\365\377\277Qn\340\217\224\343\217/Project/`

Comment: @MrMisterMan: That was just a side note. Your main problem still remains: the array isn't initialized and hence the behaviour of `strcat` is undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The malloc'd variable path contains garbage, because you never explicity fill it. Running this code in debugger may cause that it accidently sees zeroed out memory which then accidently give the expected results.

You should at least set the first character of `path` to initial zero like that:

```
path[0] = '\0';
```

Otherwise `concat()` cannot work properly.

Comment: If you malloc something is it always filled with garbage until you assign a value to it?

Comment: No it is not filled at all so you see random values which where at this place of memory.

Comment: @MrMisterMan: it isn't *actively* filled with garbage: `malloc` doesn't write garbage across it. "Garbage" is just a term meaning "memory with indeterminate value". It might be full of 0, it might be full of some value used by your debugger to detect uninitialized heap memory. It might have values that were contained in some previous allocation when it was freed. It might contain a proof of the Riemann Hypothesis (although since MAX_TITLE_SIZE is only 256, that'd be some proof).

Comment: @codymanix @Steve thanks, all is becoming clear (well, slightly less foggy)

Comment: @MrMisterMan: the important point is that almost anything you do with garbage data results in undefined behavior. We could speculate as to why your program exited cleanly instead of crashing, saying "perhaps there was a 0 in there by luck, perhaps not", but that's all specific to your machine. As far as the C language is concerned, you're off in Wonderland, and anything is permitted.

Comment: BTW, if you require the allocated memory to be zeroed out, you can use `calloc` instead of a `malloc` followed by `memset`.  In this case, as codymanix says, you just need to zero out the first byte.