# Why does setting a breakpoint before the execution of my code (XmlDocument.Load) prevent exception?

Tags: c#, xml, breakpoints, xmldocument, networkstream

I'm currently trying to send an XmlDocument over a NetworkStream.

Client side:
Sending a custom object of type User to the stream using a serializer.

```cs
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));
XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(_tcpStream, Encoding.Unicode);
serializer.Serialize(writer, user);
```

Server side:
Receiving the stream and loading it to a document for further processing.

```cs
static XmlElement ReceiveXmlElementFromClient(TcpClient client)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Receiving Element from client...");
           XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

           NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
           Console.WriteLine("Reading buffer.");
           byte[] bRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
           ns.Read(bRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);


           Stream reader = new MemoryStream(buffer.ToArray());
           XmlReader r = new XmlTextReader(reader);
           document.Load(r);
           // document.Save("test.xml")
           Console.WriteLine("Element received.");
           return document.DocumentElement;
       }
```

This causes a "Root element is missing"-exception.

However, when I place a breakpoint earlier in the function (although not earlier in the program) it works as intended. The document can be saved as well as having the root element extracted, all with the correct formatting (same as on client side).

I found this thread with seemingly the same problem in C: [Why does setting a breakpoint make my code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166269/why-does-setting-a-breakpoint-make-my-code-work)
Based on what I understood (have never touched C) the issue was about an empty initial value similar to:

```cs
byte[] bRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
```

Based on that I tried with a local function that returned a byte[], as well as adding all the bytes to a list respectively. None of those methods worked.

Another thread I found with an explanation that crossed my mind:
[In Java/Eclipse, why does setting a breakpoint in my code alter the effect of that statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178753/in-java-eclipse-why-does-setting-a-breakpoint-in-my-code-alter-the-effect-of-th) 
Where one answer mentions that it eventually is a thread running in the bakground that does not have time to finish before the next step. I tried this my making my thread wait by adding a stopwatch and a while-loop that broke after 5 sec, but in vain.

Now I am out of ideas, confused and would be very happy if someone could explain what the breakpoints are doing and what I am missing.

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of `ns.Read(bRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);` which gives you the actual bytes read. You are probably trying to deserialize with an incomplete buffer. You don't need to use an intermediate memory stream. Directly feed the network stream (ns) into your XmlTextReader.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I had just put the wait function in the wrong place (should be right before "Reading buffer"). It just takes time to send all of the data.